# Angular routes fail for a segment when browser refreshes

Tags: angular, routes

I have an Angular routing issue, specifically with routing.
Routing is failing more one segment

```
{path:'class',component:ClassComponent}
{path:'class/student',component:StudentComponent}
```

1. localhost:/3000/class
2. localhost:/300/class/student

First one works but the second one fails when the browser refreshes or when I write the URL manually.

Comment: Is your project deployed? You've to add a fallback url to index.html on your server's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
localhost/300/class/student
```

Should be

```
localhost:3000/class/student
```

Comment: thanks Jain, that was a typo in writing the question but the correction was actually what i have in my code

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I would suggest one thing, Enable `routerTracing` in router configuration, You will get to know what's getting wrong.

Comment: for more information on the same please refer https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/deep-dive-into-angular-routing-scrolling-to-top-debugging-and-lot-more-a995c08498d3

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not clear to me and what I figured is you cannot navigate to `class/student`. If this is the case then,

It should be like this

```
{path:'class/student',component:StudentComponent}
{path:'class',component:ClassComponent}
```

or you can do this

```
{path:'class', component:ClassComponent}
{path:'class/student', component:StudentComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
```

In your case 'class' in the url is satisfied so it does not change.